# Stack tracing java errors with dollar

Tags: android, debugging

I am debugging my android application which is giving me the following stack trace on google developer account.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>       at com.ramropatro.app.fragmentOCR$5.onClick (fragmentOCR.java)
>       at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5721)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22620)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7406)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

As per my knowledge there is something wrong in the java file fragmentOCR.java and when user clicks on some buttons. However, i am unknown about the dollar and number appended on fragmentOCR$5. I have a little knowledge that $5 means fifth anonymous java class inside the fragmentOCR java class. Is there any mechanism to find exactly the fifth anonymous class?

In addition, what other things are revealed by the stack trace above? I am using latest android studio. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner classes  used as event handlers

Comment: How can i reach exactly to the right event handlers. What does 5 mean? Can you just elaborate so that i understand in depth?

Comment: I would say it is 5th such inner class  - usually there shall be line number

Comment: there is no more deptht do dive into -  there was some null reference dereferenced (attempted to) in event handler - sometimes it is obvious when you look into code.  sometimes you have to debug.